# PHP - Initialize object members with array parameter

Tags: php, spl

Is it possible to initialize an objects private or protected members in php with an associative array.

for example:

```
    class TestClass
{
    public $_name;
    public $_age;


    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        ??????
    }
}


$testClass = new TestClass(
    array(
        'name'  => 'Bob',
        'age' => '29',
    )
);
```

i was wondering whether there is an elegant solution - perhaps by  implementing one the spl interfaces or otherwise?

Comment: the obvious solution is just `$this->_name = $params['name'];` in the constructor.  What does your object do?  Would the solution need to be anything more complex than that?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer - the example provided is a simplified use case.  In reality there will be a lot of properties to set - all of which are optional.

Comment: something just looping over `$this` or `$params` would solve?  You mentioned SPL - were you thinking of having the purpose of the object behave as an array or something?

Comment: yes, i thought there may be a solution like that using spl

Comment: Just do it, it works. How to do that depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned SPL.  But without knowing the exact requirements for the purpose of your object, the below is about the only information I can give...

You could have your object extend the SPL built-in class `ArrayIterator`.  Then, without concern for handling it in the constructor (already handled in the parent `ArrayIterator` class), you could import an array into your object simply like so:

```
class testClass extends ArrayIterator
{

 /* child '__construct' method not required */

 /* rest of your code here */

}

$t = new testClass(array('name' => 'asdf', 'age' => 99));
```

Keep in mind that with default `ArrayIterator` behavior, you cannot later access any of the passed array values as you would with a normal object property.  You must access them as you would an array:

```
echo $t['name']; // 'asdf'
echo $t->name; // NULL property unknown error
```

And, internally, the passed array is stored within your object as a single private `storage` parameter.  In your case, you already have all your object properties pre-defined and prepended with an underscore, so you would probably have to manually loop over `$this` or `$params` anyway in your constructor to set any real object properties.

You could of course redefine all your child object's `ArrayIterator` inherited methods to handle your special property naming case on `get` or `set`, but this would seem redundant and unproductive as opposed to just looping over `$params`/setting `$this` anyway in your constructor.

```
    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            if (property_exists($this, "_$key")) {
                $this->{"_$key"} = $val;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, just looping over `$params`/setting `$this` within your constructor is probably the best, most simple solution there is.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($params as $key=>$value)
{
 $key = '_'.$key;
 $this->$key=$value;
}
```

See the code online for working sample [here](http://codepad.org/JTExIeOr)

Comment: That's what the line `$key = '_' . $key` is for. It changes `'age'` to `'_age'` and `'name'` to `'_name'`.